# Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.ref.limitToLast') error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing some issues with my react native codes as shown below and am unable to figure out why this keep happening. I am sure that the error is coming from the `refOn` method located on my firebaseSDK file.

```
refOn = callback => {
    this.ref
      .limitToLast(20)
      .on('child_added', snapshot => callback(this.parse(snapshot)));
  }
```

When i navigate to my chat page, the `componentDidMount` method is called and in turn the `refOn` method to see al the previous messages being sent.

```
componentDidMount() {
        firebaseSDK.refOn(message => 
          this.setState(previousState => ({
            messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, message),
            })
          )
        );
      }
```

The error am getting is:

```
TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.ref.limitToLast')
```

Basically it is a chat application from 
https://blog.jscrambler.com/build-a-chat-app-with-firebase-and-react-native/..

Without the `refOn` method, the error was coming from the `componentDidMount()` method giving me the same error but with the `refOn` method, now the error is coming from this.

Edit:
Git repository for all the files
https://github.com/KrishnaRamdin/ReactNative_Chat-Room

Comment: The error message looks a but unusual to me, but it seems like `_this.ref` isn't set. Where did you set that in your code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have updated the detail above containing github link to all the files. Thank you

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't answer my question about how you initialize `_this.ref`. If you don't initialize `_this.ref` anywhere, that is probably causing problems. I'm also having a hard time understanding what `firebaseSDK.refOn` should be referring to as it's not part of the standard Firebase SDK, and I don't see where it'd be declared. You might be better off studying the Firebase documentation for web developers, for examples that are more succinct and to the point.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i misunderstood your comments. Its fix now..as you said, i needed to define the this.ref and once i did that..it fixed the issue.. 
get ref() {
    return firebase.database().ref('Messages');
  }
This is the code ive used to fix this issue..Thank you for your clarification...